# Issue with Exchange 2010 - Get-MailboxDatabase -status

Tags: powershell, backup, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, ca

I have 3 mail servers.

- 1st mail-server for the CAS.
- 2nd mail-server for the Hub-Transport.
- 3rd mail-server for the DR/DAG.

I am backing up my 1st and 2nd server with CA ARCServ 16.5 with the following conditions:

- Daily Incremental.
- Weekly Full.
- Weekly Verify.

When the backup job is running, I check everytime that the 'BackupInProgress' field is on True and it is.

Now the issue we are having is when I use the following command:

```
Get-Mailboxdatabase -status | Fl *backup*
```

The LastFullBackup, LastIncrementalBackup, LastDifferentialBackup are empty\blank

```
BackupInProgress               : False
SnapshotLastFullBackup         :
SnapshotLastIncrementalBackup  :
SnapshotLastDifferentialBackup :
SnapshotLastCopyBackup         : True
LastFullBackup                 :
LastIncrementalBackup          :
LastDifferentialBackup         :
LastCopyBackup                 : 19/08/2013 21:01:19
RetainDeletedItemsUntilBackup  : False
```

How come thode field are not being updated once the backup job is done?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are the backup settings?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your backup software isn't doing an Exchange-aware backup. You may need to install or configure a specific agent/component of the software to do an Exchange-specific backup. Only then would Exchange itself know that it's been backed up -- if you are just doing a basic disk-based backup, you are not ensured that the Exchange databases can be restored to an application-consistent state.

Look into Exchange-specific features for your backup solution -- if they aren't immediately obvious, then you may need to install an additional component on the Exchange server so that the software knows that the server is running Exchange.

Comment: but when I type the following command: Get-Mailboxdatabase -status | Fl *backup* - while the backup job is running I see: BackupInProgress               : True - So the Exchange server do recognize the backup process. So how come when it ends it doesn't write the dates entries?

Answer (score 0):

I struck a similar issue with Exchange 2013 when I was using Windows Server Backup (which is already Exchange-aware if run on an Exchange server).  When I dug hard enough through Event Viewer, there was a log entry at the time of my backup referring to "VSS Copy mode".

The default VSS mode in Windows Server Backup is "VSS Copy Backup" not "VSS Full Backup".  Once I picked "full" (see screenshot), the LastFullBackup property changed (and my logs were truncated as expected).

ARCServe may have a similarly unhelpful default.

[image: Screenshot of VSS Settings page]